# Trying to write a command that begins with "%"

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to remove the first column of a document.](https://superuser.com/questions/241604/trying-to-remove-the-first-column-of-a-document)

U have found somewhere that this below should remove the first column of a document.

```
 %s/^[^\t]*\zs\t[^\t]*\ze//g
```

But when i just try to write "%" it doesn't show anything in the command line.

Any idea?